# C: I try to use linked list to read a program and count the keyword, but there is segmentation fault

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define maxline 1000
int getword(char word[],char line[],int i);
struct tnode
{
        char key[100];
        int count;
        struct tnode *next;
};
int main()
{
        struct tnode *head=NULL;
        struct tnode *current=NULL;
        struct tnode *prev=NULL;
        char s[maxline],word[100];
        int c,a,n;
        current->count=0;
        while(fgets(s,maxline,stdin)>0)
        {
                c=0;
                while(getword(word,s,c)>0)
                {
                        if(strlen(word)<=1)
                        {
                                c++;
                                continue;
                        }
                        c=getword(word,s,c);
                        current=(struct tnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
                        current->next=NULL;
                        a=strlen(word);
                        strncpy(current->key,word,a);
                        current->key[a+1]='\0';
                        if(head==NULL)
                        {
                                (current->count)++;
                                head=current;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                prev=current;
                                current=head;
                                while(current!=NULL)
                                {
                                        n=0;
                                        if(strcmp(current->key,prev->key)==0)
                                        {
                                                (current->count)++;
                                                 n=1;
                                        }
                                        current=current->next;
                                }
                                if(n==0)
                                {
                                        current=prev;
                                        (current->count)++;
                                }
                        }
                }    
        }
        current=head;
        while(current!=NULL)
        {
        printf("%s:%d",current->key,current->count);
        current=current->next;
        }
}
int getword(char word[],char line[],int i)
{
        int n;
        if(line[i]=='\0')
        {
                return -1;
        }
        if((line[i]>='a' && line[i]<='z') || (line[i]>='A' && line[i]<='Z'))
        {
                for(n=0;n<=maxline && (isalnum(line[i])!=0 || line[i]=='.');n++,i++)
                {
                        word[n]=line[i];
                }
                word[n]='\0';
        }
        else
        {
                word[0]='\0';
        }
        i++;
        return i;
}
```

I'm trying to do when i read this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{

    int apple, banana, cat;

    apple=5;

    banana=10;

    cat=apple+banana;

    banana++;

    printf("%d\t%d\t%d",apple, banana, cat);

}
```

and the output should be:

```
banana 5

apple 4

cat 3

int 2

include 1

printf 1

stdio.h 1

main 1
```

Comment: Well that sounds nice. What have you tried and where are you stuck? What is causing the issue and what don't you understand. SO is not a place to say: my code is broken. Fix it?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Also, `current->count=0;` in the first `main` you posted would cause a null pointer exception because you explicitly set current to null and then dereferenced it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Tip of the day:

Learn to use a debugger.

### Let's show an example of using a debugger with gdb:

```
[3:02pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] gcc -g foo.c -o foo
[3:03pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] gdb ./foo
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1824) (Wed Feb  6 22:51:23 UTC 2013)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".../Users/wlynch/.gdbinit:1: Error in sourced command file:
Undefined command: "add-auto-load-safe-path".  Try "help".
Reading symbols for shared libraries .. done

(gdb) run
Starting program: /private/tmp/foo 
Reading symbols for shared libraries +.............................. done

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000064
0x0000000100000b1c in main () at foo.c:20
20          current->count=0;
(gdb) p current
$1 = (struct tnode *) 0x0
(gdb)
```

On line 20, when you do `current->count = 0;`, `current` points to `NULL`, which means you are dereferencing the null pointer which is not allowed.

Comment: +1 for showing how raw gdb works